# Can I split 6” flex duct into 4” flex duct to run between rafters, then rejoin to 6”?

Tags: hvac, ceiling, roof

I am building out my attic, and need to run a 6” insulated flex duct between 2x6 roof rafters to a register in the ceiling. The 6” duct is too big to fit between the 2x6 rafters. Can I use a Y to split the 6” duct to two 4” ducts to run between the 2x6 roof rafters, then use another Y to rejoin the two 4” ducts back to a 6” flex duct prior to connecting to the register in the ceiling?  The 4” insulated flex ducts will fit within the 2x6 roof rafters. Thanks, and please advise.

Comment: Why not use a duct designed for that space, such as a 4x10?

Comment: Welcome, Bill. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. If you don't intend to pursue a solution, please delete the question.

Comment: This is what **oval** is for. Unless they're on like 6" centers  then "having the contractor add a fir down to enclose the duct" is the option.

Answer (score 2):

That would work fine, but be careful not to use a 4-4-4 wye. Use a 6-6-4 wye, then reduce the 6 to a 4 to get the two 4s. Connect the mirror image at the other end. Also wrap the fittings with foil backed insulation, or cover it with batts. I have never seen a 6-4-4 wye. They may exist but a 6-6-4 is commonplace.

Comment: Should be mentioned, that the overlappings of those flex ducts must be in the same direction, otherwise it could be possible, that water drops out of the connectors...?

Comment: "Use a 6-6-4 wye" Should that be "Use a 6-6-_6_ wye", instead?

Comment: 6-4-4 to split one 6 into two 4s?

Comment: I think, @gnicko, that John was suggesting a 6-6-6, then use reducers on each of the outputs to get down to 4". Why he's suggesting that, I don't know. Maybe he'll come back and update his answer to indicate why that's better and to correct the 6-6-4 typo or explain exactly what that is. Also, not using a 4-4-4 wye makes sense, since at least one of the inputs should probably be 6" to match up with the incoming 6" duct.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I’m having the contractor add a fir down to enclose the duct. This is the simplest option and won’t affect the airflow.

Comment: Google "6-4-4 Wye"... Home Depot, Lowe's, Menards, Ferguson, etc, etc. I was just wondering if it was a typo. or there was an air-flow related reason for 6-6-4 with a reducer.

Answer (score 1):

Using my old Airserco air duct calculator (or "duct-O-later as we used to call them)and setting the friction reference point at .08"WC,  a 6" round duct will move 100 cfm of air while a 4" round duct will move about 32 cfm of air. So, 2-4" ducts will move only about 64 cfm or 64% of the necessary air supply to that register. There are many ways to fix your problem but without actual pictures of the structure we would all be just guessing on the FIX.